# How to move CSS to bottom of inspect window

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Probably a stupid question, but I cannot find **anything** on this.

Normally my CSS selector/editor is always at the bottom, although this time its not and I'm not too sure about how to move it back down to its normal position.[image]

Anybody able to help?

Comment: Click on the three dots on the right side and be amazed.

Comment: I don't mean the docking position, I mean specifically the CSS editor/selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the **gear icon** to open preferences tab of setting.
[Before Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPGfW.png)

Under Appearance section, set **Panel Layout** to '**horizontal**'.
[Panel Layout Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moMEx.png)

After closing the settings, the CSS will be back at the bottom.
[CSS on Bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJg8g.png)